# Replace row name by variable

Tags: php, pimcore

In this code :

```
$structuredData->setRow_1__column_1($var1);
```

is there a way to replace `Row_1` by a variable `$row` ?

https://pimcore.com/docs/pimcore/current/Development_Documentation/Objects/Object_Classes/Data_Types/Structured_Table.html

Comment: You could try `$var = "set".$asd."__column_1"; $structuredData->$var($var1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP supports [variable functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php), meaning you can use a variable that contains a sting + parentheses to call a function with that name. Here's how that works in your case:

```
$row = 'Row_6';

$setRow = "set{$row}__column_1"; 

$structuredData->$setRow($var1);
```

Comment: This is basically what Juan Eizmendi also commented, the only difference here is the string interpolation  of `$row`.